# Use JSONArray in another class?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have got a spinner that loads the name of the customers in the dropdown.

The spinner gets the string from a JSON array. 
I have also got a few textviews where the Name,Adress,Telephone number of the selected customer should load when the spinners selection changes.

But the JSONArray is used in another class, how can I use the JSONArray in another class?(How can I load the correct customer details when spinner selection changes?)

This my code:

```
     public class Gegevens extends Main {

            Spinner spCustomers;


            private JSONObject jsonChildNode;
            private JSONArray jsonMainNode;
            private String name;
            private TextView txtNaam;
            private TextView txtAdres;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_gegevens);
                new AsyncLoadCustDetails().execute();
                spCustomers = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spKlanten);
                spCustomers.setOnItemSelectedListener(new mySelectedListener());
                txtNaam = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtNaam);



            }


            protected class AsyncLoadCustDetails extends
                    AsyncTask<Void, JSONObject, ArrayList<String>> {
                ArrayList<CustomerDetailsTable> custTable = null;

                @Override
                protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {

                    RestAPI api = new RestAPI();
                    ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = null;
                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObj = api.GetCustomerDetails();

                        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

                        custTable = parser.parseCustomerDetails(jsonObj);
                        spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
//All i can think of is make new array for each value?

                        Log.d("Customers: ", jsonObj.toString());
                        jsonMainNode = jsonObj.optJSONArray("Value");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                            jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                            name = jsonChildNode.optString("Naam");


                            spinnerArray.add(name);
                        }


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("AsyncLoadCustDetails", e.getMessage());

                    }

                    return spinnerArray;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> spinnerArray) {
                    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, spinnerArray);
                    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item); // The drop down view
                    spCustomers.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

                }



            }

            public class mySelectedListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int pos, long id) {



                    String value = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                    txtNaam.setText(value); //got the name working since it wasnt that hard
    //load the other details in the textviews

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
                }

            }
        }
```

This is what the jsonObj looks like:

```
{
  "Successful": true,
  "Value": [
    {
      "Naam": "Google",
      "Adres": "Kerkstraat 3",
      "Postcode": "4455 AK Roosendaal",
      "Telefoon": "0165-559234",
      "Email": "info@google.nl",
      "Website": "www.google.nl"
    },
    {
      "Naam": "Apple",
      "Adres": "Kerkstraat 4",
      "Postcode": "4455 AD Roosendaal",
      "Telefoon": "0164-559234",
      "Email": "info@apple.nl",
      "Website": "www.apple.nl"
    }
  ]
}
```

(Only 2 "customers", since its dummy data)

Comment: You want to send `spinnerArray` to other activity?

Comment: If you will have too many customers I will suggest to create a database and save the entries into it.
You could use 3rd party libraries to simplify the work just like:
http://greendao-orm.com or http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml

Comment: I am getting this JSON array from a webAPI already(which gets the data from a database)

Comment: okay, so if you your app should work offline. I find the best way is to "_recreate_" the same database as the one on the web and use it in your app. The data will be overall accessible and using an ORM library you don't need to parse the objects manually etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the JsonArray to string as follow :

```
String jsonString = jsonArray.toString();
```

save it in shared preference :

```
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(
                            "pref", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("jsonString", jsonString);
                    editor.commit();
```

And then access it in other class.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(
                            "pref", 0);
                    String jsonString= settings 
                            .getString("jsonString", null);
```

Once you have obtained the String, convert it back to JsonArray :

```
JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use across different components, another option is to use Parcelable Interface. The following is a Pojo class with elements  name and job_title that has made as an object which can be passed across intents using interface **Parcelable**

```
public class ContactPojo implements Parcelable{
       private String name;
       private String job_title;
       public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
       }

       public void setJob_title(String job_title) {
        this.job_title = job_title;
       }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getJob_title() {
        return job_title;
    }
    private ContactPojo(Parcel parcel){
        name=parcel.readString();
        job_title=parcel.readString();
    }
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
        parcel.writeString(name);
        parcel.writeString(job_title);
    }
public static final Parcelable.Creator<ContactPojo> CREATOR = new
            Parcelable.Creator<ContactPojo>() {
                public ContactPojo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                    return new ContactPojo(in);
                }

                public ContactPojo[] newArray(int size) {
                    return new ContactPojo[size];
    }};
}
```

You can populate the pojo class by the doing the following

```
ContactPojo contactPojo= new ContactPojo();
contactPojo.setName("name");
contactPojo.setJob_title("name");
```

and send it to ext intent by this

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this, DetailView.class);
intent.putExtra("Data", contactPojo);
```

Retrieve the data in next intent by next steps

```
ContactPojo contactPojo=new ContactPojo();
contactPojo=getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Data");
Log.i(AppConstants.APPUILOG, "Name: " + contactPojo.getName() );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save your json in a file and then can fetch it in Another class or anywhere like this :

class to handle saving and fetching of data :

```
public class RetriveandSaveJSONdatafromfile {

 public static String objectToFile(Object object) throws IOException {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "/AppName/App_cache" + File.separator;
        File dir = new File(path);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        path += "data";
        File data = new File(path);
        if (!data.createNewFile()) {
            data.delete();
            data.createNewFile();
        }
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(data));
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(object);
        objectOutputStream.close();
        return path;
    }

    public static Object objectFromFile(String path) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Object object = null;
        File data = new File(path);
        if(data.exists()) {
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(data));
            object = objectInputStream.readObject();
            objectInputStream.close();
        }
        return object;
    }
}
```

To save json in a file use `RetriveandSaveJSONdatafromfile.objectToFile(obj)` and to fetch data from file use

```
 path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator +   
"/AppName/App_cache/data" + File.separator; 
 RetriveandSaveJSONdatafromfile.objectFromFile(path);
```

Answer (score 1):

1)you can get the intsance of the other class in your mainactivity and pass the json data as a string response

2)Use broadcast listener and service. Write your json response in a service and send it back to the mainactivity using a broadcast intent. The broadcast receiver in your main activity can listen to the service, which has the json data. Also update the textviews.